# How do I install matplotlib on pyCharm

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

I'm new to python and I'm using PyCharm as my IDE. I've been able to successfully install other packages like numpy, pandas etc. However, when I'm installing matplotlib, I keep getting the error:
***src/checkdep_freetype2.c(5): fatal error C1189: #error:  "FreeType version 2.3 or higher is required. You may set the MPLLOCALFREETYPE environment variable to 1 to let Matplotlib download it."***

I installed it through the command prompt and it installed correctly but (I believe) PyCharm creates it's own environment and does not recognize packages installed through command prompt even though I tried to install them in the same path as other packages in PyCharm. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

I had to run the command "pip install updates" and after that I could install the matplotlib package. It turns out that my pip wasn't of the latest version.